# What is Scala's equivalent of java char[]?

Tags: java, scala

In Java class i have an abstract method `characters(char[] in)`, as we can see it takes `char[]` as argument, I want to implement this class in my Scala but not able to find a correct way to write signature of characters in Scala. I have tried this:

```
override def characters(ch: Array[Char], start: Integer, length: Integer)
```

But this signature does not match with characters method declared in Java class. Please suggest.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just `Array[Char]`. There is no need for additional `start` and `length` parameters.

And if there *are* `start` and `length` parameters in the original Java signature (but you're not showing them), then I bet they are `int`s, and so in Scala they should be `Int`s, not `Integer`s.

Comment: My Bad. yes they are there in actual java api, and these needs to be Int in scala. Resolved

Answer (score 0):

Because everything is consider an object in Scala, you could try to gather them as separate objects in their intended form, and then cast them to char.
In native form:

```
scala> your_var.asInstanceOf[Char]
res0: Char = a
```

or with casting:

```
scala> your_var.toChar
res1: Char = a
```